# Better way to change string "abc..z" to "bcd..a"?

Tags: java, string, format, token

I created this code that looks at a string token and formats it so that every character is moved along by one. The characters are all lowercase and from a to z.

So if my input is
**abcz**

Output is
**bcda**

Right now I added all the alphabets to an arraylist, and the code determines the index of each character and adds one to it. If it finds z, it prints a so that index of the arraylist is not out of range.

```
List<String> letters = new ArrayList<String>(); 
        String alp = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        for (int i = 0; i<26; i++)
        {
            letters.add(Character.toString(alp.charAt(i)));
        }

        String token = sc.next();
        for (int i = 0; i<token.length(); i++)
        {
            if (letters.get(letters.indexOf(Character.toString(token.charAt(i)))).equals("z"))
            {
                System.out.print("a");
            }
            else
            {
            System.out.print(letters.get(letters.indexOf(Character.toString(token.charAt(i)))+1));
            }
        }
```

Comment: So what is your question? What kind of improvement are you looking for: less code, better performance, better coding style? Did you experience any problems with your implementation? What is the context, what do you need this function for?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698290/promoting-letters-in-a-string-to-the-next-letter-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple loop with a bit of modular arithmetic will do, why bother with so many objects?

```
for(int i = 0; i < token.length(); ++i) {
    System.out.print(('a' + (token.charAt(i) + 1 - 'a')%('z' - 'a' + 1)));
}
```

We increase the offset from `'a'` by one, and take the remainder modulo 26 to get an offset in the range from 0 to 25.

Comment: Troo dat, but 26 is shorter.

Comment: But @vladr's solution allows more flexibility, for instance if he wants to advance it to a rot13 or similar more "advanced" encryption.

Answer (score 2):

[Apache commons-lang library](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) has the [`StringUtils.replaceChars()`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#replaceChars%28java.lang.String,%20char,%20char%29) utility method that can do this for you:

```
StringUtils.replaceChars(input, "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", "bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza");
```

Although with such large parameters, it looks a little on the ugly side.

Nevertheless, it is just one line, and IMHO the best kind of code is someone else's code (meaning, if there's a library out there that does it, be inclined to use it).