# Promoting letters in a string to previous letter in java

Tags: java

I have method based on this link [Promoting letters in a string to next letter in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698290/promoting-letters-in-a-string-to-the-next-letter-in-java)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int shiftValue = 5;
    String foo = "abcdefxyz";
    String bar = "";

    for (char c : foo.toCharArray()) {
       bar += Character.toString((char) (((c - 'a' - shiftValue) % 26) 
       + 'a'));
    }

    System.out.println(bar);
}
```

and the output:
[image: Output]

How can I get output "yzabc" instead of "_`abc" ?

Comment: To shift 1 left, shift 25 right, to prevent negative intermediate results. Alternatively, use `(c == 'a' ? 'z' : (char) (c - 1))`.

Comment: @Andreas can give me more explanation?

Comment: `'a' - 'a' - 2 = -2` and `-2 % 26 = -2`, not `24`. To shift 2 left, you need to shift 24 right, i.e. `'a' - 'a' + 24 = 24` and `24 % 26 = 24`, aka `y`, and `'z' - 'a' + 24 = 49` and `49 % 26 = 23`, aka `x`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply shift 2 to the left, and make sure to catch the cases that go negative (in this case, a and b). So in your for-loop, use this (long but easy to read i hope):

```
        switch (c) {
            case 'a':
                bar += 'y';
                break;
            case 'b':
                bar += 'z';
                break;
            default:
                bar += (char) (c - 2);
        }
```

Or, if you want it shorter

```
bar += c > 'b' ? (char) (c-2) : (char) (c+24);
```

Explanation: if the character is bigger than b, you can just subtract 2 (e.g. c-2=a), otherwise you add 24 (e.g. a+24=y)