# First letter in a string to increase, last letter to decrease

Tags: javascript, string

I'm trying to create a simple encoder, where the first letter of every word becomes it's successor (A = B) and the last letter becomes its predecessor (B = A).

Like so:

```html
KEY: The first letter goes up, the last letter goes backwards.
</p>

If it is the first letter in the string, <span style='color: red;'>x</span> should be converted to <span style='color: blue;'>y</span>, as seen below:
</p>
<span style='color: red;'>Aa</span> = <span style='color: blue;'>Bb</span>
</p>
<span style='color: red;'>Bb</span> = <span style='color: blue;'>Cc</span>
</p>
<span style='color: red;'>Cc</span> = <span style='color: blue;'>Dd</span>
</p>
<span style='color: red;'>Dd</span> = <span style='color: blue;'>Ee</span>
</p>
and so on....
</p>
If it is the last letter in the string, <span style='color: lightgreen;'>x</span> should be converted to <span style='color: orange;'>y</span>, as seen below:
</p>
<span style='color: lightgreen;'>Aa</span> = <span style='color: orange;'>Zz</span>
</p>
<span style='color: lightgreen;'>Bb</span> = <span style='color: orange;'>Aa</span>
</p>
<span style='color: lightgreen;'>Cc</span> = <span style='color: orange;'>Bb</span>
</p>
<span style='color: lightgreen;'>Dd</span> = <span style='color: orange;'>Cc</span>
</p>
and so on....
</p>

<div class="encode">
  The fox jumped over the dog. = Uhd gow kumpec pveq uhd eoh.
</div>
```

I'm trying to accomplish this using javaScript, however, I am open to using any language that will make this possible.

This code is the gist of what I'm looking for, but I need to target the first and last letter of every word in a div:

```
var strRandomString = "I have 2 apples and 6 oranges and 3 grapes";
strRandomString.replace(/apples|oranges/g, function(m) {
    // `m` is a matched string.
    return m === 'apples' ? 'oranges' : 'apples';
})
// => "I have 2 oranges and 6 apples and 3 grapes"
```

Unfortunately, I do not have any actual sample javaScript code (but the above code can count as an attempt, a failed one), as I've been researching for about half an hour and couldn't find a viable solution.

I've scoured the following threads for help:

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/32620/replacing-every-letter-in-a-string-with-the-letter-following-it-in-the-alphabet

[Promoting letters in a string to previous letter in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43480539/promoting-letters-in-a-string-to-previous-letter-in-java)

https://coderanch.com/t/552363/java/Replacing-characters-string

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/326746-question-shifting-characters-to-the-next-letter-in-the-alphabet/

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4027-excel-increase-letter-by-one.html (yep, I was so desperate that I was about to use excel).

Comment: What if the first letter is `z`? It can't increase.

Comment: What's your problem with using the code given in [one of the questions you linked to](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/32620/replacing-every-letter-in-a-string-with-the-letter-following-it-in-the-alphabet)? I don't understand the question, it seems that you already have the answer linked in the question.

Comment: @user202729 I'm not yet a master of javaScript, and I didn't fully understand that code. However, I did attempt to implement it and it prompted me with a JavaScript alert dropdown, and told me to enter a string. The output was nowhere to be found. I had no idea what the code was actually saying in order to edit it. If you do, your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Then go learn Javascript. There are plenty of Javascript tutorials on the Internet.

Comment: @user202729 It would be ideal for `z` to just wrap back around to `a`.

Comment: @user202729 I'm a student, and I don't have a lot of time to learn new languages at this time. Trust me, I want to. However, at this current time, all I am capable of is extensive research. This research has ended in code that I'm not able to modify, which is why I am here.

Comment: Uh... don't worry, I know plenty of languages, including [weird ones](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjk3@jxpmGB5a9qhpzaOGmQZgxsPdPd7////PzCsoLVEoSa0oAQA) <-- this doesn't support wraparound. I recommend learn a language seriously and try to understand everything.

Comment: @user202729 That's perfect, thank you! Considering the fact that there aren't many words that I use that start with 'z' I think I'll be fine. If you want to submit this as an answer and receive some reputation for it, I'll mark you as best answer.

Comment: ... remember that, asking other people to write code for you doesn't help you to improve your programming skill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for a word, but also a phrase

```
function transform(phrase)
{ var i,last,letters,words=phrase.split(/\s+/);
  for(i=0;i<words.length;i++)
  { letters=words[i].split('');
    last=letters.length-1;
    letters[0]=letters[0].charCodeAt(0)<122?String.fromCharCode(letters[0].charCodeAt(0)+1):'a';
    letters[last]=97<letters[last].charCodeAt(0)?String.fromCharCode(letters[last].charCodeAt(0)-1):'z';
    words[i]=letters.join('');
  }
  return words.join(' ');
}

console.log(transform('apple zebra variables'));
//outputs 'bppld aebrz wariabler'
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This was really convenient in the sense that it can be seen directly on my console. Congrats on making 200 rep! If you join a different stack community, you'll get +100 here and +100 there. (1 time bonus on each only). So, your rep will instantly go up to 308 here.

Answer (score 1):

To make it obvious, I simply created some functions then call them.

Issues with this, single letter words like "a" get double messed with so "a" becomes "z" then back to "a" as the first and last letter.

```js
// I used this to remove the empty "" from the array, there might be better ways that altering the prototype but that might be opinion.
Array.prototype.clean = function(deleteValue) {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    if (this[i] == deleteValue) {
      this.splice(i, 1);
      i--;
    }
  }
  return this;
};
// wrap to begin using same case
function prevLetter(letter) {
  if (letter === 'a') {
    return 'z';
  }
  if (letter === 'A') {
    return 'Z';
  }
  return String.fromCharCode(letter.charCodeAt(0) - 1);
}
// wrap to end using same case
function nextLetter(letter) {
  if (letter === 'z') {
    return 'a';
  }
  if (letter === 'Z') {
    return 'A';
  }
  return String.fromCharCode(letter.charCodeAt(0) + 1);
}
// last letter of word
function getLastLetter(myword) {
  return myword.slice(-1);
}
// first letter of word
function getFirstLetter(myword) {
  return myword.charAt(0);
}
//split sentence into array by the ;,. and space
function splitString(mystring) {
  return mystring.split(/[ ;,.]+/);
}
// replace a character (first,last)
function setCharAt(mystring, index, chr) {
  if (index > mystring.length - 1) return mystring;
  return mystring.substr(0, index) + chr + mystring.substr(index + 1);
}
var mySentence = "The big,  brown; cow ran over a zebra. I get this";
// words in the sentence to mess with
var splitS = splitString(mySentence).clean("");

for (var i = 0; i < splitS.length; i++) {
  var newS = setCharAt(splitS[i], 0, nextLetter(getFirstLetter(splitS[i])));
  var newSE = setCharAt(newS, newS.length - 1, prevLetter(getLastLetter(newS)));
  splitS[i] = newSE;
}
// the words in the array now are messed with
console.log(splitS);
```

Comment: Note this is not the most compact solution however it should be easily understood.  Do what you want with the final array, I made no attempt to preserve the non-alpha but they could be put back in place using the original sentence as a pattern.  Add more to the `splitString` if other characters might need to be split on.